# How to delete buttons in a message

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have a message, when I click the "Принять" button, I need to delete the other two buttons.
Method create buttons
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBkJZ.png)

```
EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
User user = event.getUser();
eb.setAuthor(user.getAsTag(), null,user.getAvatarUrl());
eb.addField("Ник", Objects.requireNonNull(event.getValue("nick")).getAsString(), true);
eb.addField("О себе", Objects.requireNonNull(event.getValue("biography")).getAsString(), true);
event.replyEmbeds(eb.build()).addActionRow(
        net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.components.buttons.Button.success("yes", "Принять"),
        Button.danger("no", "Отклонить")
).queue();
```

```
event.getMessage().getActionRows().clear();

event.getMessage().getComponents().clear();
```

But the result is 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You said 'delete the other two buttons' but there is only one other button shown in your code and the screenshot. Are you wanting to delete both buttons or or just the "Отклонить" one? It's hard to tell from your question, but I think you're looking for this https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#editMessageComponents(net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.components.ComponentLayout...)

Comment: i want to delete both button.

Answer (score 2):

The .clear() method removes all elements from a list. This means you are getting
the **event.getMessage().getActionRows()** as a **List** and then removing its contents, but you are not performing any actual actions to the message. Remember that every action like this would need a **.queue()** at the end, look out for it in the future ;)

Here is my take on solving the problem, did not check if it works, but it logically should:

```
     if(event.getButton().getId().equals("Принять")){
        List<ItemComponent> actionRow = event.getMessage().getActionRows().get(0).getComponents();
        actionRow.remove(1);
        actionRow.remove(2);
        event.getMessage().editMessage(event.getMessage().getContentRaw()).setActionRow(actionRow).queue();
    }
```

So you basically get the list of current components in the first ActionRow
then you remove the ones you do not need from the list using **actionRow.remove()**
then you simply edit the message with new action rows :)